opt-out from prevent caching of HTTP requests that require authorization
I have angular application with SSR and hydration
here is example of my app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
  ],
};

according to this PR in Angular https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/55034

BREAKING CHANGE: By default we now prevent caching of HTTP requests that require authorization . To opt-out from this behaviour use the includeRequestsWithAuthHeaders option in withHttpTransferCache.


Example:

withHttpTransferCache({
  includeRequestsWithAuthHeaders: true,
})

now I don't know where exactly I can import withHttpTransferCache
I tried all of the following
import { withHttpTransferCache } from '@angular/common/http';
import { withHttpTransferCache } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { withHttpTransferCache } from '@angular/core';

but I always get the error TS2305: Module "@angular/core" has no exported member withHttpTransferCache
and the usual auto import doesn't work for me

I think the provider is removed instead you have a configure transfer cache object inside the provideClientHydration. We can use the filter option to filter the routes related to auth!
We can customize the transferCache with the provider withHttpTransferCacheOptions which has an input object HttpTransferCacheOptions with the below properties.
type HttpTransferCacheOptions = {
    includeHeaders?: string[];
    filter?: (req: HttpRequest<unknown>) => boolean;
    includePostRequests?: boolean;
};

So we can use the filter property to filter out routes which we want to filter
Angular Github Code
/**
 * Options to configure how TransferCache should be used to cache requests made via HttpClient.
 *
 * @param includeHeaders Specifies which headers should be included into cached responses. No
 *     headers are included by default.
 * @param filter A function that receives a request as an argument and returns a boolean to indicate
 *     whether a request should be included into the cache.
 * @param includePostRequests Enables caching for POST requests. By default, only GET and HEAD
 *     requests are cached. This option can be enabled if POST requests are used to retrieve data
 *     (for example using GraphQL).
 * @param includeRequestsWithAuthHeaders Enables caching of requests containing either `Authorization`
 *     or `Proxy-Authorization` headers. By default, these requests are excluded from caching.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export type HttpTransferCacheOptions = {
  includeHeaders?: string[];
  filter?: (req: HttpRequest<unknown>) => boolean;
  includePostRequests?: boolean;
  includeRequestsWithAuthHeaders?: boolean;
};

Final code:
...
provideClientHydration(
    withHttpTransferCacheOptions({
        filter: req => !req.url.startsWith('https://internal')
    })
);
...


where to import withHttpTransferCache from?

can you please replace withHttpTransferCache with withHttpTransferCacheOptions in your final code

@Robert Sorry typo!
